# MySQL getting tables info where

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling to link 2 tables together so that I can fill out information for my PHP script

I have 2 tables `feed` and `u_feed`

```
U_FEED
id | uid | fid
1  | 2   |  1

FEED
id | url               | title  | favicon
1  | http://example.com | domain | http://example.com/favicon.ico
```

The current user id (uid) will be `2`

I have tried but to no luck

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
JOIN feed f ON u.fid = '2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying what column to join the two tables on, and it looks like you're using the wrong column to filter based on the User Id. Try something like this:

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
INNER JOIN feed f ON f.id = u.fid
WHERE u.uid = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one first join your tables then use `WHERE`

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
JOIN feed f ON u.fid = f.id
WHERE  u.fid='2'
```

Or

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
JOIN feed f ON (u.fid = f.id AND u.fid='2' )// join tables with multiple conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the JOIN condition correctly. There must a column in both tables that correspond to each other. In this case it seems to be `u_feed.fid` and `feed.id`.

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
JOIN feed f ON f.id = u.fid
WHERE u.uid = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a typo or confusion - you said

> The current user id (uid) will be 2

but query by fid = 2.

```
SELECT u.uid, f.url, f.title, f.favicon
FROM u_feed u
JOIN feed f ON u.fid = f.id
WHERE u.uid = 2
```

Hope this helps